# Can Same spring batch invoked with different job parameter from different multiple thread at the same time

Tags: spring-batch

Our requirement is to write multiple files at the same time. we are using spring batch to write file and we are lunching the spring batch from different thread. Each thread will have it is own application context. So we can assure that the singletone beans will not be shared across multiple thread. Below is my code snippet.

Spring batch config.

```
<bean id="reportDataReader" class="com.test.ist.batch2.rrm.batch.readers.RRMItmeReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="verifyCursorPosition" value="false" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="#{jobParameters['sqlquery']}" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="valueMapper" />
    <property name="fetchSize" value="5000" />
</bean>

<bean id="valueMapper" class="com.test.ist.batch2.rrm.batch.mappers.DBValueMapper" scope="step"></bean>

<bean id="velocityFileWritter"
    class="com.test.ist.batch2.rrm.batch.writers.RRMVelocityFileWriter"
    scope="step">
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine"
    class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <value>
            resource.loader = class
            class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            class.resource.loader.cache = true
            class.resource.loader.modificationCheckInterval = 0
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<batch:job id="rrmReportGenJob">
    <batch:step id="rrmReportGenStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="reportDataReader" writer="velocityFileWritter"
                commit-interval="${reportData.reader.commit-interval}">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

This how we are invoking the spring batch.

ThreadPoolExecutor tpe=new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 1000000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,  new LinkedBlockingQueue());
        PetReportGenerator rrg=new PetReportGenerator(null);
        ThreadTest tt=new ThreadTest(new PetReportGenerator(null), "161");
        ThreadTest tt2=new ThreadTest(new PetReportGenerator(null), "162");
        ThreadTest tt3=new ThreadTest(new PetReportGenerator(null), "163");
        ThreadTest tt4=new ThreadTest(new PetReportGenerator(null), "165");
        tpe.execute(tt);
        tpe.execute(tt2);
        tpe.execute(tt3);
        tpe.execute(tt4);

In the constructor of PetReportGenerator we are initializing the bean config.
Below is the code snippet

private ApplicationContext appContext;

```
public PetReportGenerator(ApplicationContext reportContext){
    if(null == reportContext){
        //if(null == appContext){
        appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-batch-jobs.xml");
        //}
    }else{
        setAppContext(reportContext);;
    }
}
```

Below is the code extract of how we invoke the spring batch

Job jobToExecute = (Job)SpringUtils.getBean(jobName);
            JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
            //By default add the Data time. This will help to lauch the same job again with same parameters
            paramsBuilder.addLong("JOB_TIME", System.currentTimeMillis());
            if(!jobParams.isEmpty()){
                //Validate input fields.
                String sqlToUse = validator.validateInput(jobParams);
                for(Map.Entry entry:jobParams.entrySet()){

```
                    paramsBuilder.addString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

            }

        }else{
            throw new ReportGenerationException("Job input parameter is Empty");
        }

        jobexe=jobLauncher.run(jobToExecute, paramsBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

If it is run in a single thread it is working fine.
When it is invoked by multiple threads we are getting below error

09:09:26,742 ERROR pool-1-thread-3 job.AbstractJob:329 - Encountered fatal error executing job
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.synchronizeStatus(MapJobExecutionDao.java:158)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.updateStatus(AbstractJob.java:416)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:299)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)

Can any one please help me to understand what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The `MapJobRepository` is **NOT** intended for production use.  It is **NOT** threadsafe.  If you need the performance of in memory job repositories (loosing restartability, etc), use an in memory database like HSQLDB.

That note aside, if you are using thread safe components, there is no reason you can't launch multiple job instances with multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that the MapJobExecutionDao is threadsafe in all aspects? I see, that a ConcurrentMap is used in side MapJobExecutionDao, but I'm not sure if this is enough. I once had a problem getting also a NullPointer from a Map that was accessed from different threads. The problem there was, that one thread caused a rehashing and when the second thread did access the map at that very moment, it received a nullpointer.

Are you sure, that the combinations of your identifying jobparameters is unique? I see, that you add a parameter Job_Time with System.currentTimeMillis(), but do you know, if that really resolves in an unique timestamp?

Have you tried to use the table based versions of JobExecutionDao and so on?